# Basic programming in arducopter

Tags: arduino, ardupilot

I am starting with a project using Arducopter. I am a person familiar with arduino, but seeing the arducopter for the first time. Commands codes and everything is completly different compared to normal Arduino programming. I am not getting any help or commandlist for specific purposes in arducopter. Any body can help me in leading to any links which can help me out..

Comment: did you find what you were seeking with arducopter? I am learning it inside and out to be able to mix and match.

Answer (score 3):

You should start with http://dev.ardupilot.com/
You can find articles that will make you familarize with code.

Alternatively you can look at Aeroquad(https://github.com/AeroQuad/AeroQuad) which runs quadcopter on Arduino

Comment: these two are the ones among the very few documents available in the net.... but they are actually telling us to get idea about the programming language by simply evaluating the sample programs... we are unable to get a guidance like we have for arduino and other microcontrollers... thats what that actually troubling us....

Comment: Developing quadcopter covers vast area like hardware integration, sensor integration, control, calibrations etc. and there are not many resources for combined development. So I would suggest you spend time in  reading code and understanding it by yourself. Arducopter uses modified arduino environment to make code efficient and compatible over various platforms. Although it is little complex, it is not that hard if you keep patience.